# This transaction is invalid. Paypal PHP SDK

Tags: php, paypal

My Paypal PHP SDK code is suddenly giving me issues in sandbox mode. As of a few hours ago, it consistently gives me a "This transaction is invalid" error upon redirection to Paypal, which has never happened before. Paypal doesn't seem to give me any indication as to why the transaction is even invalid to begin with. This code has been deployed since tuesday last week and only recently started giving this issue. This is but part of the code, but this is where I create the payment and get the URL from it.

```
        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent("sale")
                ->setPayer($payer)
                ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
                ->setExperienceProfileId($profileid)
                ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

        try {
            $payment->create($apiContext);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getCode();
            echo $ex->getData();
            exit();
        }

        $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

        header("Location: $approvalUrl");

        exit;
```

When I var_dump $approvalUrl, I get the following:

```
string(86) "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6BK51071ES8856135"
```

Is there something wrong with my token or the SDK? And is there any way to pinpoint what's wrong?

Comment: Having the same problem, was getting super frustrated last night.  Will wait to see it fixed.  There is also an open issue on their git page: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues

Comment: Had the same problem yesterday, now turned back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue on Paypal's end giving the wrong URL/Credentials. It is now resolved.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a problem with the approval_url.  It's pointing to www.paypal.com instead of www.sandbox.paypal.com

My guess is someone's done an update and broke things.  Mine appeared to have stopped working at some point between 11:24pm and 11:41pm BST.

Comment: Now that you mention it. That's true. I'm sending a request to a sandbox app.

Comment: Same here.  Even if you manually try and fix the URL mine doesn't get recognised.  Tried digging round for a 'report to PayPal' facility and gave up after getting redirected to knowledge bases.  I guess they'll fix it when they spot it.

Interestingly, I deleted my app from the sandbox and it still continues to process and return the non-functioning transaction URL.